# In Netezza I'm trying to use a sequence in a case statement but the sequence value doesn't increment

Tags: netezza, sequence-sql

Here is the sequence creation syntax used:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE BD_ID_SEQ AS INTEGER
    START WITH 999
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE 
    NO MAXVALUE 
    NO CYCLE;
```

I have a table with the following values records:

```
b_id
-------
2547
NULL
2800
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

I run the following:

```
select case 
          when b_id is NULL then cast((select next value for bd_id_seq) as character varying(10)) 
          else b_id 
       end b_id
from table1;
```

The result comes to:

```
b_id
-------
2547
1000
2800
1000
1000
1000
1000
```

I was expecting:

```
2547
1000
2800
1001
1002
1003
1004
```

Any ideas why in the case statement the sequence doesn't seem to increment past the first value?
Thanks,
Ginni

Answer (score 6):

you need to change the way you are calling the next value.  Just remove the `select` and request the next value.  Like below.

```
select case 
          when b_id is NULL then cast((next value for bd_id_seq) as character varying(10)) 
          else b_id 
       end b_id
from table1;
```

Comment: Why is this not an answer? Thanks @Niederee